# python time conversion into proper time format

Tags: python, time

I need to convert

```
u'2013-07-16T16:14:34+0000'
```

into

```
July 16, 2013 4:14 pm
```

Is there a way to do this in python?

I got this, but it is not right:

```
>>> from datetime import *
>>> from time import *
>>> thetime = u'2013-07-16T16:14:34+0000'
>>> finaltime = datetime(*strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000")[0:6]).strftime('%m-%d-%Y  %H:%M')
'07-16-2013  16:14'
```

Comment: As an aside: You don't want to be doing `from foo import *` except in a very few circumstances.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime

Comment: And you don't need to use the `time` module's version of `strptime` at all - `datetime.datetime.strptime(...).strftime(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> datetime(*strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000")[0:6]).strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p")
'July 16, 2013 04:14 PM'
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `time.strptime`, which returns a time tuple, you could use `datetime.strptime`, which returns a datetime object:

```
import datetime as DT
thetime = '2013-07-16T16:14:34+0000'
finaltime = DT.datetime.strptime(thetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000").strftime('%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p')
print(finaltime)
```

yields

```
July 16, 2013 04:14 PM
```

---

With Python2.7.5 or better, you can also use the [%z directive](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to parse the UTC offset instead of using the fixed string `+0000`:

```
DT.datetime.strptime(thetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```